# Extending F# List Module

Tags: list, f#, module, extension-methods

I've been adding a few handy methods to some of the F# modules such as List.

```
type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList<'a> with          //'
    static member iterWhile (f:'a -> bool) (ls:'a list) = 
        let rec iterLoop f ls = 
            match ls with
            | head :: tail -> if f head then iterLoop f tail
            | _ -> ()
        iterLoop f ls
```

and i'm wondering if it's possible to add mutation?  I know List is immutable so how about adding a mutable method to Ref of type List.  Something like this.

```
type Ref<'a when 'a :> Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList<'a> > with //'
    member this.AppendMutate element =
        this := element :: !this
```

or is there some way to constrain a generic to only accept a mutable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic extension methods are now available in F# 3.1:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type Utils () =
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline AppendMutate(ref: Ref<List<'a>>, elt) = ref := elt :: !ref

let ls = ref [1..10]

ls.AppendMutate(11)

printfn "%A" ls
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be possible to add extension members to closed constructed types (e.g. `Ref<int>` or `Seq<string>`).  This also applies to the code you're trying to use, since you're substituting the more specific type `'a list` for the generic parameter `'T` of the open generic `Ref<'T>` type.