# Is there a way to extend the generic type IStore<ValueTuple<K, V>> dependant on K and V in F#?

Tags: generics, f#

In C# I can extent the type IStore<ValueTuple<K, V>> with this extension method

```
public static void F<K, V>(this IStore<ValueTuple<K, V>> s, K k)
```

I do not see a way to extent IStore<ValueTuple<K, V>> in a similar way using F#. The closest I can think if is to express the ValueTuple specification via a constraint, but that does not work:

```
type IStore<'kv when 'kv :> ValueTuple<'k, int> > with
   member o.F(k: 'K) = 42
```

Is there a way to express this in F# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208542/20092784

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type Extensions () =
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline F<'K, 'V>(o: IStore<ValueTuple<'K, 'V>>, k: 'K) = 42
```

Answer (score 1):

As of some later version of F# (when we got struct tuples), you can also do

```
type IStore<'T> with
    static member f<'K> ((s: IStore<(struct('K * int))>), (k: 'K)) = 42
```